# Connect to remote DB2 from Linux command line

Tags: linux, db2, debian

I want to connect to a remote DB2 instance running DB2 for I. Basically I want to batch load data from the DB2 and pipe it into a local postgres innstance.

My machine has a Debian Jessie and I downloaded and installed *IBM Data Server Runtime Client (Linux AMD64 and Intel EM64T)*

I tested the connection via a Database Management tool (dbeaver) and it works. However I can't get the CLI to work in any mode. I tried following the IBM guides (like https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/comref/src/tpc/db2z_clpconnectsyntax.html) but to no avail.

Above guide suggests:

```
db2 => CONNECT TO myIP:myPort/myDB USER myid01 USING mypw01
```

But I get

```
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "myIP:myPort/myDB" was found following 
"TO".  Expected tokens may include:  "<database-alias>".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

I can't find anything that works in the IBM documentary.

Comment: use CONNECT myIP:myPort/myDB USER myid01 USING mypw01

Comment: You're looking at the wrong documentation if you are using DB2 on IBM i.

Comment: I did not find anything remotely related to what I want do do in the DB2 for I docs :(

Answer (score 2):

The error states:

```
Expected tokens may include:  "<database-alias>"
```

You need to add it in your command such as:

```
db2 => CONNECT TO myIP:myPort/DB_ALIAS.myDB USER myid01 USING mypw01
```

The database_alias can be created by cataloging the connection (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSNY3_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.client.doc/doc/t0005621.html). You may need to run the following commands:

```
$ db2 catalog tcpip node SERVER_NAME remote SERVER_IP server SERVER_TCP_PORT
$ db2 catalog database DB_NAME as DB_ALIAS at node SERVER_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I did it and on trying to connect I got:

    db2 => CONNECT to DB_NAME USER myid01 USING mypw01
    SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected.         Communication protocol 
    being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".      Location 
    where the error was detected: "myIP".  Communication function detecting 
    the error: "recv".  Protocol specific error code(s): "*", "*", "0".  
SQLSTATE=08001

Comment: Unfortunately, I have run out of ideas @Kaylon ...

Possibly, all the configuration needs to be reviewed, and possibly considering using [IBM DB2 JDBC Driver for the connection](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866).

Comment: Yeah, I will probably hack a small python CLI which just do this one use case. At least there is a DB2 for I5 driver that integrates with sqlalchemy. Still thanks a lot for your input!

Comment: The communication error you're getting indicates that you're getting a timeout when trying to connect. Are you sure you have the right IP/host name? Could there be a firewall between you and the database preventing your connection?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created catalog then even no require to pass IP address and port detail it will connect easily to that database(just make an alias of database) only where you have made catalog like an steps below.

1. db2 catalog TCPIP node mynode remote XX.XX.XX.XX server 50000 --> Normal step.
2. db2 catalog database mydatabase as AKUMAR at node mynode --> AKUMAR is the alias of mydatabase
3. db2 connect to akumar user userid using pwd
   it will connect to remote database only which has supplied db IP(XX.XX.XX.XX)